# How can you enable the selection margin in Visual Studio Code (VSCode)

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to enable the selection margin in Visual Studio Code (VSCode)? By "selection margin" I mean the margin to the left of the text that allows you to select entire lines by clicking and dragging with the mouse.

I'm aware of triple-click.  That's not what I'm after.  Visual Studio (proper) has a so-called "selection margin", and I was hoping Visual Studio Code would have the same thing but it seems like it may not be there, or I just haven't figured out how to get it.

I also see a breakpoint margin, and the code folding area (or some dead-space if you disable the code folding). But that area doesn't work like a selection margin either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must show the line numbers through `settings.json` file:

```
// Controls visibility of line numbers
"editor.lineNumbers": true,
```

Then, when hovering that area, you'll see the inverted mouse to select the entire line, as you wish:

[image: Selecting multiple lines in VSCode]

Comment: Oh no!  No other way?  The line numbers are the first thing I shut off.  I don't want them.  Can I cheat and colorize the line numbers the same as the background or something tricky?

Comment: If there is other way, I really don't know it :P

Comment: About colorizing the line numbers, probably you can do that by creating a theme and setting it the same as the background in textMate.